# MDI menu shortcut not working while other Form active

Tags: vb.net, mdi

My project have MDI form and it 's have a menu with many shortcut 
all shortcut work fine while it 's  focus  but when I open any form all shortcut stop working because the MDI form not active 
How I can send keyboard press to the mdi form to trigger the menu shortcut

this how i open child window

```
 FrmChild.Owner = Me
 FrmChild.Show()
```

I make the key press , key down events static and public and but them in the key press ,key down in the child form it 's work and I sent the keyboard input to the MDI form but menu shortcut never trigger.

frmMDI

```
Public Shared Sub frmMDI_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

End Sub
```

frmChild

```
Private Sub FrmChild_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    frmMDI.frmMDI_KeyDown(sender, e)
End Sub
```

thanks.

Comment: Typically the active Window receives a keyboard shortcut, so your app works as expected. Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the call in the child keydown handler to the mdiparent keydown handler. The menu shortcut of the parent will work without this. The reason it's not working is because you should have

```
FrmChild.MdiParent = Me
```

instead of

```
FrmChild.Owner = Me
```

Comment: yes you are right  but I did this in purpose .. because childForms are to big and show them in front of the mdi is good form me :)

Comment: It will work work with the keydown handlers if you use normal form instead of an MDI Parent.

Comment: I try but it's not working can you give me more information the but  way is to understand how the shortcut trigger

Comment: Sorry, I meant the keydown handlers will work with a normal form. They menu shortcuts will only work with a properly configured MDI Parent and Child.